# Spring webflow - mvc controller as subflow

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, spring-webflow

Is there a way of using spring MVC contollers as subflows in spring webflow?

I have some data browsers written as plain MVC controllers and I would like to use them in my flows to browse/select data.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve my problem. I am using a view state pointing to an external url (my controller). Here is the example:

```
<view-state id="itemBrowser" view="externalRedirect:contextRelative:/itemBrowser?callbackUrl=#{flowExecutionUrl}&amp;itemSelectionMode=true">
    <transition on="itemSelected" to="wizardStepBasic">
        <evaluate expression="wizardActions.onItemSelected"/>
    </transition>
</view-state>
```

The 'callbackUrl' parameter is used at the controller side to return to the flow. For example:

```
<a href=${callbackUrl}&selectedItemId=${item.id}&_eventId_itemSelected>
    <img src="static/images/accept.png"/>
</a>
```

Hope, it'll be of some help to somebody :-)